# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'signaloff' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to read ultrasonic range when a button is pressed on a raspberry pi.

I'm getting a random error that happens about 1 in three times. Have also tried running 'print reading(0)' three times with a wait of 2 seconds in between each attempt and sometimes it works and sometimes it fails on the first try.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 37, in <module>
    print reading(0)
  File "test.py", line 30, in reading
    timepassed = signalon - signaloff
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'signaloff' referenced before assignment
```

The code is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# btn on pin 18
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
# LED on pin 24
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
# GPIO output = the pin that's connected to "Trig" on the sensor
# GPIO input = the pin that's connected to "Echo" on the sensor
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.IN)

def reading(sensor):

    if sensor == 0:
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(0.3)

        GPIO.output(17, True)
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.output(17, False)
        while GPIO.input(27) == 0:
            signaloff = time.time()

        while GPIO.input(27) == 1:
            signalon = time.time()

        timepassed = signalon - signaloff
        distance = timepassed * 17000

        return distance
    else:
        print "Incorrect usonic() function varible."

while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(18)
    if input_state == False:
        print('Button Pressed')
        GPIO.output(24, True)
        print reading(0)
        time.sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(24, False)
```

Comment: Do you even understand how that error comes to happen? It's a common confusion and a little research should show you what it means. BTW: `print "error message"` is not error handling, raise an exception instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `GPIO.input(27)` returns 0 the first time you call it, the while loop will never be entered, and `signaloff` will never be set. The same is actually true for the loop that set `signalon`, although that issue might be rarer.